# Specific proof related to MDS distance matrix

Tags: self-study, matrix, distance, multidimensional-scaling

Given a symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix **A**, and matrix **D**, where $D_{ij}=A_{ii}-2A_{ij}+A_{jj}$, prove that there exist n vectors {$\vec{v_1},...,\vec{v_n}$} such that $D_{ij}=||\vec{v_i}-\vec{v_j}||^2_2$.

I am stuck after writing out $$D_{ij}=<\vec{v_i} \vec{v_i}> -2<\vec{v_i} \vec{v_j}> + <\vec{v_j}\vec{v_j}>$$and do not know how to proceed proving this.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Thank you, yes it is, I edited it.

Comment: You have shown that the squared Euclidean distances in $D$ correspond to the dot products in $A$. So, if there exist $n$ vectors whose dot products match $A$, then their squared distances will match $D$. What remains is to show that there exist vectors whose dot products match $A$. Hint: If the vectors are on the rows of a matrix $V$, then the dot products are $V V^T$

Comment: Right, thank you! So then what's needed is to prove $A=VV^t$, but this is already a property of matrix $A$ (positive semidefinite).